# My github username/password considered to be invalid after upgrading git

Tags: git, github

## Summary

All git functions, `git push`, etc worked fine, username/password credentials worked fine when I was using git v1.9.2

But after upgrading git to *v1.9.4* (or even the latest as of today: *2.5.0-rc1*), I get

```
remote: Invalid username or password.
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://kaushalmodi@github.com/kaushalmodi/.emacs.d.git/'
```

## Research

I have already scoured all the SO posts answering this issue but my case is different because:

- I cannot use ssh as that port is blocked at work.
- I have already verified that I do not have 2-factor authentication enabled.
- The same username/password used to work on git 1.9.2 and still works on github.com and Windows Github GUI; it just doesn't work the same way through linux CLI.
- I even tried enabling the 2-factor authentication and using the token passphrase (generated on github.com) as the password and that still gives the same error as above.

## Git Config

### Global

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = false
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
[user]
    name = Kaushal Modi
    email = kaushal.modi@gmail.com
[credential]
    helper = cache --timeout 7200
[push]
    default = matching
```

### Local (my emacs config repo)

```
[remote "origin"]
    url = https://kaushalmodi@github.com/kaushalmodi/.emacs.d.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "master"]
    merge = refs/heads/master
    remote = origin
[submodule "software/reveal.js"]
    url = http://github.com/hakimel/reveal.js
[submodule "elisp/zenburn-emacs"]
    url = https://kaushalmodi@github.com/kaushalmodi/zenburn-emacs
[submodule "elisp/unfill"]
    url = https://kaushalmodi@github.com/kaushalmodi/unfill
[submodule "elisp/smyx"]
    url = https://kaushalmodi@github.com/kaushalmodi/smyx
[submodule "elisp/outshine"]
    url = https://kaushalmodi@github.com/kaushalmodi/outshine
[submodule "elisp/poporg"]
    url = https://kaushalmodi@github.com/kaushalmodi/poporg
[submodule "elisp/verilog-mode"]
    url = https://kaushalmodi@github.com/kaushalmodi/verilog-mode
```

## System Info

- RHEL 5.10
- git version

  - 1.9.2 (admin installed worked)
  - 1.9.4 (self-installed in my $HOME **does not work**)
- curl 7.43.0
- openssl 1.0.2c

## Question

**What am I missing when upgrading git that causes it to think that the username/password are incorrect?**

- I need a solution that uses **https** (not ssh)

Answer (score 0):

You need to check what your https password is at GitHub first. You may have some additional data in .netrc (which is where the password may be cached) or your credential helper may be supplying the wrong password to GitHub. Try doing a standalone clone of one of the repositories using https and the username to see if you get prompted for a password in a different directory, and/or check the .netrc file doesn't have anything cached.

Comment: I do not use the .netrc approach.. I simply cache it for a set time. The password is not saved encrypted or otherwise anywhere. I can assure that my https password is fine because using the exact same password, authentication works when using the sysadmin installed git version 1.9.2, but fails when using my installed git version 1.9.4. To test this, I set up a system so that I can easily switch between the two versions.

Comment: I cloned that repo to a different folder and `git push` using my locally installed `git` version failed there too.